# Combining Git with Gradle and Various IDE's

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, gradle

I've been working on a Java project using Gradle in Eclipse that builds on my local machine and works just fine. I want the project to be available to a team of developers via Git, but after creating the repository and trying to build on a different machine using both IntelliJ and Eclipse, I'm realizing that there are some challenges. For instance, it seems like there need to be minor changes in build.gradle. Or in IntelliJ, JDK 1.8.0 must be specified for java.util.stream.

My goal is to create a project that allows a team of developers to simply clone the repository, use any IDE they want, build the project and begin contributing right away. Has anyone attempted to do this before with Gradle? What are some tips or insights? Is Gradle a poor choice for this? How can I standardize the build, libraries, etc.?

Comment: use gitignore to ignore files from each ide https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: you (and each of your team mates) need to put some system dependend  information  (e.g. path to JDK/JRE)  into a local gradle configuration file <https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html>. this must be maintained by each team member separately to meet her system environment.